# MongoDB Delete all documents that created by user when deleting user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on MongoDB (mongoose) and NodeJS. I have a problem. I'm makine a RESTful API. I have Users model (collection) and Comments model (collection). Users creates comments, and i relate the User and User's Comments with User's _id. l want to delete all comments when user deleted. How can I make this in MongoDB? I search it on Google for 2 days but İ l can't find a good source, looked at MongoDB Manual Documents, but i didn't find anything.

Please help me. Thanks, have a good day...

Comment: Please post an example of the data structure you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support built-in relations and transactions among collections.

To remove related Comments (I suppose you have `userId` field in each `Comment`):

```
db.comments.remove({userId: removedUserId})
```

If you have collection of ids of comments in User, then:

```
db.comments.remove({id: {$in: collectionOfCommentIds}})
```

---

Mongoose does support [middlewares](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). But notice that

> There is no query hook for remove(), only for documents.

So you can define `remove` hook for use with `user.remove()`. But not for `User.remove({_id: userId})`

```
userSchema.post(`remove`, (user) => {
    Comments.remove({userId: user._id})
})
```

Comment: the `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the *specified array*. `collectionOfCommentIds` requires an array...

Comment: Alright. Thanks so much @iofjuupasli. You helped me too much :)

Comment: @Rags-2-Riches Yup, it can be helpful when needed. Thanks for description +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parent referencing

```
    userSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async id => {
      await Comments.deleteMany({ user: id });
    });
```

If you are using child referencing

```
   userSchema.post("findOneAndDelete", async function (user) {
      if (user.comments.length) {
        const res = await Comment.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: user.comments } });
        console.log(res);
      }
   });
```